# С# как передать (пробросить) все аргументы в вызываемую функцию?

Tags: c#, рефлексия

Есть функция `f1(x,y,z)`, `f2(a,b)` ... `fn(x1,x2)`. n>50 Есть база данных, из которой хранимыми функциями можно получить данные. Reflection даёт только имена аргументов без значений, можно ли как-то "пробросить" значения всех аргументов?

```
 void f1(int x, int y, int z) { caller_hlp(/*???*/); }

void caller_hlp( /*???*/ ){
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();            
            MethodBase mb = (new System.Diagnostics.StackFrame(1)).GetMethod();
            cmd.Connection = get_conn();
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.CommandText = mb.Name; /*Имя вызвавшей функции*/
            foreach (ParameterInfo pi in  mb.GetParameters()) {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(pi.Name /*имя вызвавшего параметра*/, null /*???*/ );
               }
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();      
 }
```

В js в браузере аргументы родителя, к примеру, можно получить так `arguments.callee.caller.arguments[i]` и аргументы не передавать вообще.

```
  var fname =  arguments.callee.caller.toString().match(/ ([^\(]+)/)[1]; 
  var arg_names=arguments.callee.caller.arguments.callee.toString().match(/(([^\)]+)/)[1].split(",");   
   arguments.callee.caller.arguments[i];  // и значения аргументов
```

В c# так гибко не получается.

Вариант перечислять аргументы каждый раз - не подходит. Пробовал `__arglist` - не получилось.

Как можно c# получить значение аргументов вызвавшей функции?

Comment: `params` не подходит в вашем случае?

Comment: Не знаю, поможет ли, но, пробовали делать примерно так? https://pastebin.com/g3Chz3NX

Comment: Вот блин, уже в который раз не успеваю ответить первым)

Comment: params упрощает задачу, но всёравно заставляет перечислить все параметры, т.е. нужно `f(x,y) { caller(x,y); }` делать.

Comment: `f(params int[] p) { caller(p); }`

Comment: @test123 - так или имена аргументов теряются (они важны для хранимки). Либо всёравно приходиться их перечислять.

Comment: так, а где заставляет кто перечислять параметры? вызывать будете как и написали: f1(1,3,4); f1("1","2"); на функцию caller_hlp вся пачка и будет приходить, разве что, придётся её распаковать

Comment: хм, ну если имена имеют большее значение чем тип, то это какая то странная магия... подозреваю, надо будет ещё с метаданными мудрить, или вешать свои атрибуты... Скажите, если не секрет, что хотите иметь в конечном итоге?

Comment: Может тогда передавать словарь имеет смысл?

Comment: @Андрей, можно хоть словарём, хоть Tuple использовать, но, не понятно для чего это надо, узнать бы что он хочет)

Comment: @test123, ну всё же именно словарь представляет собой пары ключ-значение, что и требуется автору, судя по всему

Comment: Хочу вытащить значения агрументов вызвавшей функции, например из стека. В с++ и js эта проблема решаема. Интересно есть ли такая возможность в c#.

Comment: Мне кажется я понял суть вопроса. У вас 50 методов с именами f1,f2,f3,f4... вы слышали что нибудь об интерфейсах? Пожалуйста, посмотрите в сторону списка из интерфейсов. Ваше решение очень странное...

Comment: Если вы пишите на шарпе, не думайте мышлением с++, тем более js. Тут подобные вещи избыточны...

Comment: По поводу "стека функции", в шарпе есть такая возможность, но, только в рамках класса. Вы должны создать экземпляр вашего класса, внутри которого будет эта функция, тогда вы сможете вытащить необходимые данные, но, это очень ресурсозатратная операция.

Comment: @test123 да, это в рамках одного класса. Где можно почитать про стек?

Comment: @nick_n_a, ну и подкинули вы работы)) Испробовал несколько вариантов, вот один из них http://evain.net/blog/articles/2009/04/30/reflection-based-cil-reader/ Но, даже с таким разбором не смог сделать рабочий вариант. Я так понимаю, сама информация в методах не хранится, и десериализуется только в конкретный момент времени, так что, вынимать её придётся на низком уровне, либо, самостоятельно куда то записывать данные. Всё таки, настолько красочно как вы хотели, вряд ли получится... придётся, таки, самостоятельно запаковывать аргументы. Тут только IDictionary<string,object> в голову приходит...

Comment: Идея "трейсера" вообще мне в голову приходила, даже валяются наброски, но не в контексте этой задачи. Я пытался через ref получить адрес - но адрес на кучу указывает (где всё как-попало разбросано). Пробовал esp получить - но сложно накопать нужный "фрейм".

Comment: И в тему вашего кода, тот же hibernate практически полностью реализуется аннотациями (атрибутами), отсюда, вызов такого рода функций сводится к заполнению DTO объекта, либо к извлечению данных из такого DTO объекта в SQL. Может вам такой подход подойдёт)